# Is threre any function to make a chrome driver - headless while using chrome extention in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

```
page_main = fn.init_chrome_driver()
page_details = fn.init_chrome_driver()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_extension("extention.crx")
page_main = 

webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Got this error:

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl/src/background/index.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl/src/background/index.html
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The issue is with the extension. The headless specification (option) is correct